# Cannot use interface for my generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I have this small bit of code that is going through a list to check for overlaps:

```
private List<INode> _nodes = new List<INode>();
private List<ISegment> _segments = new List<ISegment>();
public IReadOnlyList<INode> Nodes => _nodes;
public IReadOnlyList<ISegment> Segments => _segments;

private bool Overlaps<T>(ref Vector3 point, in IReadOnlyList<T> collection, out T obj) where T : INode, ISegment
{
    obj = default;
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
    {
        if (collection[i].Overlaps(ref point))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public bool Overlaps(ref Vector3 point, out INode node){
     return Overlaps(ref point, _nodes, out node);
}
public bool Overlaps(ref Vector3 point, out ISegment segment){
    return Overlaps(ref point, _segments, out segment);
}
```

The generic method can only accept two types, INode or ISegment which is what the `where` clause is for but i get this error :

```
The type 'Graphs.INode' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or
method 'Graph.Overlaps<T>(ref Vector3, in IReadOnlyList<T>, out T)'. There is no
implicit reference conversion from 'Graphs.INode' to 'Graphs.ISegment'.
```

Not sure i understand why it thinks I am converting, am I using the `where` keyword wrong here? Not sure how to get this working.

Interface definitions:

```
public interface INode{
    bool Overlaps(ref Vector3 point);
}
public interface ISegment{
    bool Overlaps(ref Vector3 point);
}
```

Comment: We need to see the definition of `INode`, `ISegment`, and as well as the actual types you're passing into `Overlaps`.

Comment: "The generic method can only accept two types, `INode` or `ISegment` which is what the where clause is for" <-- That is _not_ what your constraint does: it doesn't restrict `T` to _only_ 2 types, what it does is _require_ `T` to implement _both_ interfaces.

Comment: @Dai oh - that would be the issue then, is there a way to restrict it so it will accept only those 2 interfaces, so an either/or rather than both ?

Comment: Generally speaking you can't do that - because there's no reason to. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: What is the purpose of your `out T obj` parameter? All your code does is set `obj = default`

Comment: @Dai well i some times need to test if i am overlapping a node or a segment, so depending on what i need, i made my current script under the idea of reducing duplicate code.

Comment: Also, why is `Vector3 point` being passed `ref`? Don't you want `in` instead?

Comment: Is this being used in Unity Engine?

Comment: I've not finished implementing returning the `obj` and `ref` is because i am snapping the position directly to the overlap point.

Comment: So both `INode` and `ISegment` have an `Overlaps` method? Then they should extend another common interface that defines the `Overlaps` interface, which your `Overlaps<T>` method can then enforce without needing to be generic at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` keyword says that your Generic type must implement `INode` **AND** `ISegment`.

INode and ISegments seems to have the same contracts you can build interface inheritance based on this.

```
public interface INode{
     bool Overlaps(ref Vector3 point);
}
public interface ISegment : INode { }
//OR
public interface ISegment {
     bool Overlaps(ref Vector3 point);
}
public interface INode : ISegment { }
```

**Update**

better approach is to use a common shared interface

```
public interface IOverlaps { 
    bool Overlaps(ref Vector3 point);
}
public interface INode : IOverlaps { }
public interface ISegment : IOverlaps { }

... where T : IOverlaps { ... }
```

Comment: Or `IOverlaps { bool Overlaps(ref Vector3 point); }` `INode : IOverlaps{}` etc.

Comment: Ah i understand now, i think it will make more sense to make a IOverlaps interface rather than have node/segment inherit each other! But I understand the solution ! :) thanks.

Comment: You got this right, then do to `where T : IOverlaps`

Comment: @Orkad Why bother with generics at all? Just replace `T` with `IOverlaps`. The only reason to use generics with single-interface constraints is to prevent the boxing of structs, which doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Dai because otherwise i have to do a cast on the `out` parameter in the two functions that call it.

Comment: @WDUK ...but you aren't doing anything with that `out` parameter...

Comment: See my comment about that under the question i already explained it.